# php file path require syntax for importing a page

Tags: php, relative-path

I have a directory called `images` and `about`  and 3 php file on home directory
and 3 files and have different content

footer.php

```
This is footer <img src="images/logo.png">
```

header.php

```
 <h1>Welcome to MyWebsite</h1>
```

index.php

```
<?php
require('header.php'); ?>
Enter your name : and some forms and javascript code
<?php
require('footer.php'); ?>
```

---

Now i have file in directory `about` as about.php

and it has some contents and below code is

about.php

```
<?php require('../header.php'); ?>
This is About page<br>
<?php require('../footer.php'); ?>
```

And when i open the page about.php, the footer is working fine but the image is not showing up, and `image` directory has image as `logo.png`

Even i used realpath to work out with relative paths, but could not display.
Even i tried this one too in footer.php

```
<?php 
define('__ROOT__', images(__FILE__)); 
?> 

This is footer <img src="<?php echo require_once(__ROOT__.'/logo.png);  ?>">
```

I tried out the possibilites of relatives paths, do we have any other thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this questions

copy the below code in header.php and it will work every where

```
 <?php
      define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
      define('ROOT_URL', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR))));
      ?>
```

And where ever there is a image you `src=""` just put the below code only with imagename changed, and whatever you want.

```
 <img src="<?php echo ROOT_URL .'/images/logo.jpg'; ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the easiest solution is probably just to use an absolute path for your image tag in `footer.php`:

So if `images` is in your docroot, it would look like this:

```
This is footer <img src="/images/logo.png">
```

Comment: If I give <img src="/images/logo.png">, then image at homepage is gone and its not displaying on about.php, for that i gave <img src="../images/logo.png">, then only it is only working at about.php not at homepage.

Comment: You need to put in the correct absolute URL for your setup, not necessarily the one I gave as an example.

Comment: how can we get Root relative path?

Answer (score 0):

Including images in the php file makes absolutely no sense.

You have to understand the difference between PHP code and HTML code.
PHP code being executed on the **server** and have result of HTML code sent to the **browser**.
Where browser reads that HTML and do additional requests to the server to get images.
Thus, server filesystem root has absolutely nothing to do with browser.

As for the problem - Trott's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using include() to get certain section of the Page with PHP, there will definitely be a problem with links.

I believe the best practice is to call images using CSS. Just get a div with a class or id and place the relative link in the CSS.

It worked for me.

Comment: I think, need to call the image by CSS method only.. Thanks and but can you let me know for include or require method would great